# Скрипт на Python3

Tags: linux, python-3.x

Есть такой скрипт.Помогите пожалуйста исправить ошибку.

```
import urllib
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
match = re.findall('[0-9]+', html)
print(match)
```

Показывает ошибку:
 return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: response.text не пробовали?

Comment: `b'[0-9]+'` . .